# Need to fix a regex, which replaces too much

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have such string:

```
Text [City 1 || Location] text [Population] 
|| Text [City 2 || Location] text [Population]
```

I need regex which replace || just within [] with ==.

So i must be:

```
Text [City 1 == Location] text [Population] 
|| Text [City 2 == Location] text [Population]
```

I wrote this regex:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[(.*?)\|\|(.*?)\]", "[$1==$2]");
```

But it replaces all || with ==.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid matching everything and only get the '||' like that:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\[[^\[\]]*)\|\|(?=[^\[\]]*\])", "==");
```

**So what is happening here?**

`(?<=\[[^\[\]]*)`  this is a zero width look behind that matches '[' and any character following it, other than '[' or ']'

`\|\|` this matches the actual '||'

`(?=[^\[\]]*\])` this is a zero width look ahead that matches any character other than '[' or ']', followed by ']'

Comment: Works! Thank you! Could you explane this regex? (?<=\[[^\[\]]*) and (?=[^\[\]]*\]) parts :-)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Try using `lookbehind` and `lookahead` assertions:

```
(?<= subexpression)
Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion.  

(?= subexpression)
Zero-width positive lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gave the same result. All have been replaced.

Comment: Can you explain why this is different?